# App Engine Python ndb map_async strange behavior for deletes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am using `map_async` (through the remote_api) with a very simple callback tasklet that just deletes the key that is passed. However, all the entities are *not* always deleted on the first go. In most cases, I have to run the query more than once for all entities to be deleted. The code:

```
@ndb.tasklet
def delete_key_tasklet(key):
    yield key.delete_async()

class Person(ndb.Model):
    name1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    name2 = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def delete_persons_async(cls, ancestor_key, name):
        q = cls.query(ancestor=ancestor_key)
        q = q.filter(ndb.OR(cls.name1 == name, cls.name2 == name))
        return q.map_async(delete_key_tasklet, keys_only=True)
```

For example, if I use the following query:

```
Person.delete_persons_async(ancestor_key, 'David').get_result()
```

I expect that all `Person` entities with name "David" are deleted.

- It is probably *not* an issue with eventual consistency. I have waited several minutes and flushed the memcache several times to see if the entities finally disappeared.
- If I change the tasklet to `yield key.get_async()` it correctly fetches all entities.

So:

1. Any ideas about what is going on?
2. Is it (a delete) limitation of the remote_api?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, but why aren't you using `ndb.delete_multi_async` rather than this more complicated and less performant approach ?  You have added the overhead of the call to delete_key_tasklet for no gain.

Comment: Yes, using `ndb.delete_multi_async` would work in most of my cases. The problem is that I do not know how many entities that need to be deleted so to avoid memory issues (reading too many entities to memory) I would have to read them in pages and wouldn't that give me even more overhead? In my average case though, I only have to delete about 10-50 entities so using `ndb.delete_multi_async` is probably ok.

Comment: You are doing a keys only query, so you would have to load a lot of key's into memory for that to be an issue. A believe you would be fine for hundreds of keys.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to wrap the whole operation in [`@ndb.toplevel`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#intro) or explicitly call [`ndb.Future.get_result`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/futureclass#Future_get_result) on the result of the `delete_async` return values in order to ensure the operation completes.

> if the request handler exits too early, the put might never happen